# Load mask plugin for twitter bootstrap

Tags: javascript, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is exists any bootstrap plugin (like https://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask) for masking page content when AJAX loading ?

For BS 3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is (though I don't have perfect knowledge- I am currently looking for this solution myself).

I did, however, find [this blog post](http://dotnetspeak.com/2013/05/creating-simple-please-wait-dialog-with-twitter-bootstrap) that creates one from handy Bootstrap components.

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal hide" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h1>Processing...</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="progress progress-striped active">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp;
myApp = myApp || (function () {
    var pleaseWaitDiv = $('<div class="modal hide" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false"><div class="modal-header"><h1>Processing...</h1></div><div class="modal-body"><div class="progress progress-striped active"><div class="bar" style="width: 100%;"></div></div></div></div>');
    return {
        showPleaseWait: function() {
            pleaseWaitDiv.modal();
        },
        hidePleaseWait: function () {
            pleaseWaitDiv.modal('hide');
        },

    };
})();
```

example usage:
`myApp.showPleaseWait();`

result:
[image: screenshot of the result]